# Get login post request from a webpage

Tags: java, html, authentication

I want to programmatically (using java) login to a site.

(Already have user name and password)

Take this site for example:
http://mediaforest-argentina.com/Membership/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGuests%2fRealtimeCharts.aspx

Code is as follows:

```
...
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("The url that I need");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken1", "username"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken2", "password"));
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
...
```

I need the url to the post request. How can I get it?

Comment: You need to findout login url from owner of the site.

Comment: There must be a way to find out without owner...?

Comment: Why are you messing with code if you don't even know what language it's written in?

Comment: The code, it's from the client code, not the server

Answer (score 2):

You need to examine the source code of the website, in particular the login form and look at what data is it sending. Look at `<form action="url_here" ...>`

In your example site this URL is http://mediaforest-argentina.com/Membership/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGuests%2fRealtimeCharts.aspx but note that in a lot of cases, this example being no exception, there are hidden form elements with data that you need to send with your request.
A quick look reveals a lot of hidden form elements:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTEyOTA2MDE5Ng9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIED2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPZBYCAg8PEA8WAh4HQ2hlY2tlZGhkZGRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBStjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJExvZ2luMSRSZW1lbWJlck1lBTJjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJExvZ2luMSRBZ3JlZVRlcm1zT2ZVc2FnZQ==">
<input type="hidden" name="__PREVIOUSPAGE" id="__PREVIOUSPAGE" value="HJPLOnv9G-WzfNEMvvC92zihg9ivnWKp_vC_6zv73e3_sOtSB4IhbCtPk3C75el4TZvgalSI2OHCaVGPxWZzWwUGXqo1">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCQKP7Ne4AgK/1YTzDQLu8I/0DgKh+7V7Ao+F8Z4OAsz3upgFAueno7sBAs/QlOcIAozNmZwP">
```

There may be many more, but I haven't really looked for long. Also note that there might be some tweaking of the values done by the javascript before posting the form. For that reason I recommend that you capture the full request using development tools in your browser ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, [Chrome Development Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) for Chrome etc) and base the login script on that.

I know this sounds very complicated but the reason is, that unless the site owner provides a public API, he-she probably doesnt want you logging in this way.

Comment: What is the url in my example url? (you paste the original site address in your answer)

Comment: Thats because that is the URL used by their login form.

Comment: David: You need to submit a post request to that URL

Answer (score 0):

Using something like firebug or chrome developper tools, you will be able to see the request sent when trying to login. Which is in fact the URL you just posted : http://mediaforest-argentina.com/Membership/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGuests%2fRealtimeCharts.aspx

Comment: How can it be that the site address and the login address are the same? where are the username and password in the request?

Comment: This is a post request, so the login and password are in the form data, not in URL variables. The URL ending by login.asp this is not very surpising for it to be the login page. I guess when you try to access some pages of the site without being authenticated you are redirected to this login page, nothing surprising with that.

Comment: POSt requests send data in the message body, not the headers where the URL lives.

Comment: @MarcB I don't quite understand what you mean. The first part of your sentence seems to be a repeat of what I just said in my comment? And I don't get the second part.

Comment: @kay: just stating it more clearly. "form data" can still be passed as query vars in a url.

Comment: I believed that while 'URL variables' or sometimes 'query string parameters' refer to the parameters in the URL, 'form data' always refered to the data that are sent in the resquest's body.